# Firebase transaction never calls onComplete()

Tags: java, transactions, firebase

Working with Firebase in Java, I have a situation where it seems my `Transaction.Handler.onComplete()` is never called.

I'm trying to wait for completion on a particular transaction, so I keep the calling thread from advancing until `onComplete()` is called. This is done by an anonymous decorator around the existing Transaction.Handler `txn`.

```
Transaction.Handler txn = ...
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

  @Override
  public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData data) {
    return txn.doTransaction(data);
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete(FirebaseError e, boolean wasCommitted, DataSnapshot data) {
    System.out.println("never printed");
    txn.onComplete(e, wasCommitted, data);
    if(e != null || !wasCommitted) {
      System.out.println("error: " + e + ", committed: " + wasCommitted);
    }
    latch.countDown();
  }

});

latch.await(); 
System.out.println("never printed");
```

`doTransaction()` definitely completes at least once - and I can see the data update in the web interface - but `onComplete()` is never called and we just hang.

I can't see anything wrong with this wrapper pattern: I ran the same transaction alone in a test `main()` method on a different Firebase, and `onComplete()` **was** called.

What is causing this hang? Is there something about a Firebase's configuration (e.g. auth? rules? ) that's introducing a bug here?

**EDIT**

I'm having the same problem without the wrapper pattern. Here's that code:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

  @Override
  public void onComplete(FirebaseError e, boolean b, DataSnapshot data) {
    if(e != null || !b) {
      System.out.println("error: " + e + ", committed: " + b);
    }
    System.out.println("transaction finished!");
    latch.countDown();
  }

  @Override
  public Result doTransaction(MutableData data) {
    System.out.println("doing transaction");
    data.child(...).setValue(...);
    return Transaction.success(data);
  }
});

latch.await();
System.out.println("never printed");
```

Which results in printing `doing transaction` and the data changing in the Firebase (which I see via web UI), but *not* printing `transaction finished`. It just hangs.

Comment: If there's a lot of contention on that specific spot in Firebase, it's possible that the transaction is unable to complete (since Firebase transaction are executed client side). Is there a lot of contention for that spot in Firebase?  Also, what version of the client are you using?

Comment: @JennyTong Only this process is touching that subtree of the Firebase. (If it helps, `doTransaction()` only runs a single time and then the Firebase web UI shows updates.)
I'm using JVM client 2.1.2.

Comment: It looks like you have two instances of Transaction.Handler: txn and the anonymous class you pass to ref.runTrasnaction(). You're only supposed to have one, per https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions   Can you try refactoring down to one instance?

Comment: @JennyTong Sorry if this was unclear. I updated the question above to emphasize that I'm trying to do a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). That is, the anonymous Transaction.Handler just wraps the existing instance `txn` in order to add the latch functionality. I don't see how that's a violation of the docs (or why it would be).
That said, I still have the problem without the wrapper. I edited the question above to include an example of that.   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I managed to create an app that reproduces the issue: transaction completion seems to be blocked by the call to             latch.await();  We'll investigate.  In the mean time, what are you counting down with that latch? There's probably a work around :)

Comment: @JennyTong I wanted to use this in situations where I had to wait for completion of a transaction. The alternative is chaining methods out of `onComplete()`

Answer (score 4):

On Android all Firebase callbacks are run on the main thread. If you call `latch.await()` on the main thread, `onComplete` will never have the chance to run, because the main thread is blocked, resulting in a deadlock.

Comment: Interesting. (Though as I commented above, I'm using the Firebase JVM client.)

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which JVM are you running on? Which language are you using? You also added the Android tag, so I assumed you were running on Android.

Comment: Java, Oracle JDK 8. Firebase JVM client 2.2.0 (though originally 2.1.2 when the question was written). 
Sorry, I think @JennyTong added the android tag? I'll remove it.

Comment: On the JVM I wasn't able to reproduce the deadlock. Do you mind enabling logging with `Firebase.getDefaultConfig().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);` and sending the log to support@firebase.com.